# Possible to conditionally elide out a subclass method?

Tags: scala

In Scala, I'd like to have a subclass method conditionally elided out (and revert to the base class implementation) based on the command line priority.  As an example, suppose I have the following code:

```
// File: mini.scala

import scala.annotation._, elidable._

trait FooBase {

  def bar(msg: String) = println("FooBase: " + msg)
}

object Foo extends FooBase {

  @elidable(INFO)
  override def bar(msg: String) = println("Foo: " + msg)
}

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("before")
    Foo.bar("message")
    println("after")
  }
}
```

If I compile with:

```
scalac -Xelide-below MINIMUM mini.scala
```

And run it, I see (as expected):

```
before
Foo: message
after
```

Now if I compile with:

```
scalac -Xelide-below MAXIMUM mini.scala
```

Then, I hoped to see:

```
before
FooBase: message
after
```

But I actually see:

```
before
after
```

So instead of just the subclass method being elided out (as hoped) the base class seems to be gone too.

Any explanation appreciated.

---

Based on the response from @som-snytt, it seems that the best way to achieve the effect I'm after is something like:

```
trait DebugBase {
    def on = false
}

object Debug extends DebugBase {
   @elidable(INFO)
   override def on = true
}

object Foo {
  def bar(msg: String) = if (Debug.on) println("Foo (Debug): " + msg) else println("Foo: " + msg)
}
```

But then there is still a runtime check on the status of `Debug.on` instead of completely eliding out the debug version as you might with an `#ifdef` in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good one.  I've looked at the mechanism once upon a time, but I wasn't sure about the use case.

The answer is commented:

```
/** Called if a tree's symbol is elidable.  If it's a DefDef,
 *  replace only the body/rhs with 0/false/()/null; otherwise replace
 *  the whole tree with it.
 */
```

So in eliding `Foo.bar`, you don't remove the method definition.  You merely turn it into `def bar = ()` and any invocation into the unit value `()`.

You can elide a template method usefully:

```
scala> class X { def f() = { if (g() < 1) println("default") } ; def g() = 1 }
defined class X

scala> :se -Xelide-below 200

scala> class Y extends X { @elidable(100) override def g() = 2 }
defined class Y

scala> new Y().f()
default

scala> :se -Xelide-below 5

scala> class Y extends X { @elidable(100) override def g() = 2 }
defined class Y

scala> new Y().f()
```